# Thymeleaf replacing text in table attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, thymeleaf

I am trying use thymeleaf in my current spring-boot project.

I have this piece of code:

```
   $("#issueTable td").click(function() {
      alert("You clicked -> " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });

<tr th:each="issue : ${issues}" >
<td id="issueIdTd{id}(id=${issue.id})"  class="col_id"      th:text="${issue.id}"  ></td><!-- ID -->
```

But on the alert I see `"You clicked -> issueIdTd{id}(id=${issue.id})"`
and not the replacement of `{issue.id}` as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  thymeleaf doesn't process attributes that don't begin with `th:`.  In order to get it to process the id attribute, you have to use `th:id`.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes

Second, this syntax: `issueIdTd{id}(id=${issue.id})` only applies to url expressions (which look like `@{issueIdTd{id}(id=${issue.id})}`).  For normal use, you should just append strings together.  After all that, your td should look like this:

```
<td th:id="${'issueIdTd' + issue.id}" class="col_id" th:text="${issue.id}" />
```